# LEFT JOIN table to find non matching rows, same table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a `table` that looks like this:

```
id int primary key
uniqueID string --not uniquely indexed
foreignKeyID int --foreignKey to another table
```

I want to find all the uniqueIds in this table that exist for foreign key 1 that do not exist for foreign key 2

I thought I could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2
ON t1.uniqueID = t2.uniqueID
WHERE 
t1.foreignKeyID = 1
AND t2.uniqueID IS NULL
```

However this is never giving me results.  I can make it work with a `NOT IN` subquery but this is a very large table so I suspect a solution using joins will be faster.

Looking for the best way to structure this query.

Here's an sample data set and SQL Fiddle with an example of the working `NOT IN` query I am trying to convert to a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uniqueID` varchar(255),
  `foreignKeyID` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `table` (uniqueID, foreignKeyID) VALUES ('aaa', 1), ('bbb', 1);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48a3f3/4 and a non-working `LEFT JOIN` I thought would be equivalent.

Thanks!

Comment: @Strawberry sorry about that, added a sql fiddle.

Comment: While Minimal, I doubt that a data set comprising 2 rows can be reasonably considered Complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, seems to be working if understood the question properly:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table` t
LEFT JOIN `table` tt ON tt.uniqueID = t.uniqueID AND tt.foreignKeyID <> 1
WHERE t.foreignKeyID = 1 AND tt.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this works.  I guess adding that second condition to the ON clause changes the meaning in a way I wasn't seeing.